# Cannot unserialize object after storing it serialized in database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, serialization

I'm trying to store a complex object here and am doing that by serialising the object running a `mysql_real_escape_string` on it and inserting it into a mysql database.

However when I retrieve it running a sql query - I'm using `Zend` frameworks `Zend_DB_Table` here but anyway - and when I try to stripslashes and unserialize I dont get my object back. I've tried to just unserialize without stripping slashes and all but nothings working.

---

**UPDATE**

This is weird. I made a simple page which just unserializes a serialised object. If I take the serialized string as it is retrieved from the database and unserialize it via this other page which just has an `unserialize()` on it - it works perfectly and I get my object back. However in the code where ironically I'm retriving the string and I run the exact same unserialize option there ,its not working!

So basically there is nothing wrong with the serialized string - for some weird reason it won't unserialize it in my application but it unserializes somewhere else, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably need to run it through base64 encoding first:

```
$safe_string_to_store = base64_encode(serialize($data));
```

Then to get it back out:

```
$date = unserialize(base64_decode($safe_string_to_store));
```

Try that and let us know if it works.

(and dont run stripslashes on it - there is no need to)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't run `stripslashes` on it - the database will give you back the right string to put into `unserialize`.

Make sure you have notices turned on and echo the string before you unserialize it - does it look right?

Comment: How do I turn notices ON? Well I've tried to stripslash and unserialize as well as unserialize without stripping slashes and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: error_reporting(E_NOTICE);

This will enable notices, but also override your current error reporting levels.
http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php for more info

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do the following:

Assuming MyTable is your instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract:

```
$t = new MyTable();
$n = $t->createRow();
$n->serializedfield = serialize($data);
$n->save();
```

and let Zend DB take care of the escaping for you.

If you're doing it via an `insert()`, you shouldnt need to do anything either (the above uses `insert()`)

Otherwise use `$db->quoteInto()` like

```
$db->quoteInto('INSERT INTO mytable (serializedfield) values (?)', serialize($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use json_encode instead of serialize. Some day you will find yourself trying to use that data from another place that is not PHP and having it stored in JSON makes it readable everywhere; virtually every language supports decoding JSON and is a well stablished standard. And is even worse if you base64 it, you also make the serialized content unreadable from your database console client.